# Creating an iontophoretic circuitry design that is controlled by an Arduino Nano BLE Sense

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design

I'm a beginner in analogue electronic design working on a project that involves interfacing a Arduino Nano BLE Sense microcontroller to a drug patch for iontophoretic transdermal drug delivery.

I can't seem to find any good resources that involves the design of this kind of circuitry.

The initial concept is to maintain a constant current of 1mA into the electrodes meant to push the drug into the skin model.

My initial idea was to step up a battery voltage from 3.3V to 20V using a DC-DC boost converter. The using the 20V as a saturation limit for a gain amplifier that would be used to amplify the PWM from the microcontroller. The voltage across the electrodes would be measured by the microcontroller to determine whether to increase or decrease the PWM duty cycle to manipulate current flow. However, I'm not too sure on the feasibility of this method.

Would really appreciate any feedback or ideas from the community

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: I think my question would be which kind of circuit block I can start with for an iontophoretic circuit.